# Google Geocoding api error message: We're sorry... ...but your computer

Tags: google-geocoding-api

[SOLVED]

We use the Google Geocoding api.
Since few weeks ago it throws an error:

> Google     Sorry... We're sorry... ... but your computer or network may
>   be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process
>   your request right now.
>
> See Google Help for more information.

I get the longitude and latitude with php.

My url looks like:

`$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=luzern&sensor=false&key=myGoogleConsoleApiKey";`

My php function:

```
   function geturlfile($url) {

      $time_start = microtime(true);
      $cs = curl_init($url);

      curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_PORT, 80);
      curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

      $result = curl_exec($cs);

      $ce = curl_error($cs);
      curl_close($cs);

      return $result;
   }
```

The result is the error message above!

I tried:

- Use SSL instead of no ssl- https and port 443 - not working
- Add country - luzern,+switzerland - not working
- Use without a key - not working
- Call the url directly in the browser - it works !

Important facts:

- I use the same php code on another page and it works perfectly.
- Since it doesn't work, i run a script that convert 50 addresses to
  longitude and latitude. That doesn't work too and i run the script
  three times.

I think google means that we are a bot. How can I tell Google we aren't? Or what is wrong? I hope you can help me!

I forgot to mention that we use the php function in combination with a map.
We use it as a store locator: User send a form with a zip or place, we send it to google to get the latitute and longitute and show stores around the address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED]

After several tests I noticed that Google blocked the Server IP or else. I used the code on another server and it worked.

Notice: The server is a shared hosting and I have no chance to change the IP.

Caution irony !! Thank you Google for that and thank you so much for your help !!

So, i found a very nice and good alternative!
I changed 3,4 lines of code and BAM it works.

Infos: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org

Geocoding: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

Answer (score 0):

Like the Error message from Google clearly states, you performed too many requests in a given time period.

Wait a few hours until Google unblocks your IP or get a new IP address. Nevertheless when needing that many queries to the geocode API, think about caching requests at your local environment or consider "Google Maps API for Work": https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That was the first thing I tried. I wait now 1 week. Every day I tried it one time. Not working.
Get a new IP is no option, because the requests are from our webserver.
I read the documentation about the limits. We dont' need it. That was a one time thing. But I think, that's the problem.